# NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects' in Django after some time runing

Tags: python, django

I have recently migrated a Django 1.8 to Django 1.11, everything seems to work correctly, but in production, after some time running correctly, Django starts to return messages like:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

The user cannot continue using the application, each action returns an "Internal server error" (all related to 'NoneType' object ...). Even the 500 error template for Django, which I have customized, is not shown.

Django runs on Apache/WSGI.

It seems like classes and objects, in general, are suddenly 'NoneType' objects.

After a reload of Apache server, everything starts to work fine again during some time and the error comes back (after a few hours).

I have not found specific log errors that point to the cause of the error.

What is the best way to debug this kind of sporadic change of behavior? Anyone knows how to solve these kind of errors?

The same code is running in other instances on Django 1.8 and working correctly.

Adding additional information regarding traceback:

The traceback points to a line like this:

blogs = Blog.objects.filter(author=request.user)

The line is exactly the same code working fine for Django 1.8.

The traceback looks likes this, with no much detail.

AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'
uploader/forms.py in **init** at line 65
Called from: myapp/myapp_context_processors.py in addons_settings

Comment: Please post the (full) traceback, together with relevant views, models, etc.

Comment: It may be due the reason that you are calling some objects attribute in your view and that attribute can be left blank by user and have no value.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh If that were the case, it would also be happening under Django 1.8, which it is not.

Comment: Have you reviewed the Django release notes for versions 1.9, 1.10, and 1.11 to see if those versions introduced anything that would cause this?

Comment: I reviewed release notes for 1.9, 1.10, 1.11 and did not found any additional detail regarding this

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution. After looking with more detail the previous errors to the exception, I found an error that happened always sometime before the `NoneType` errors.

I had this error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class myapp.users.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

For some reason, the server "crashed" after this error.

The solution for me was to move a code that I had in myapp/views.py to myapp/users/views.py, imports of models from myapp/views.py causes the RuntimeError and subsequent errors that make the application crash.